# A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php

I have a form that passes two dates (start and finish) to a PHP script that will add those to a DB. I am having problems validating this. I keep getting the following error:

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

This is when I use the following

```
date("d",$_GET['start_date']);
```

Comment: I assume your `$_GET['start_date']` is not a [timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) which is expected by `date` function as a second argument

Answer (score 272, accepted):

This error means you are trying to use a string that contains a non-numeric value where only a number is expected.

Like in your case: `date()` expects a number (a [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) while you are passing a string, something like `2020-10-10` or `2020/10/10`.

Every time you encounter such a problem you must investigate it. First of all, print the problem value using var_dump(). Then you must decide, what to do next.

- if you are accessing a wrong variable, like some function returns an array  but you are trying to use it as a number, use `var_dump()` result to learn the array's structure and to find the right element to use.
- if the problem value can be converted to a number, then do it. Like in your case,  use `strtotime()` to convert a string date representation to a number of seconds
- if it cannot be converted, being plainly wrong, you need to fix the cause:

  - if the problem value is coming from outside, like, in the form field named 'age' someone enters `twenty two`, you need to *validate* the entered value, check if it's indeed a number and stop the form processing in case it's not, and inform the user that entered data is invalid
  - if some your function returns incorrect value, like, $22 instead of 22, you must fix that function or change the logic of your application: you must do all calculations first, and format the numbers later.

What you should **never do** is just mindlessly cast the problem value to a number, as suggested in some answers. Casting won't fix the problem. It will just sweep it under the rug and often will give you outright incorrect value. Besides, casting effectively works as error suppression, so when some your function will start returning incorrect value, casting will start silently returning 0, leaving you unaware of the problem.

Comment: I get the same error in the constructor of a class, i was debugging and the problem in that constructor is I'm receiving as a parameter and integer `public function __construct(int $someId....)`

Comment: With parameter typing in PHP becoming more the 'norm', what @MarcosDiPaolo mentioned will definitely be seen more frequently. A dead giveaway is the stack trace will point to the line of the parameter declaration that's being incorrectly typed.

Comment: I still don't understand what is the course of action here @parttimeturtle

Comment: @MarcosDiPaolo the Types of parameters you pass to that constructor must match the Types that are being hinted in the function definition. "4" represented by a string is different from 4 represented by an integer. So either conform to the function definition or turn off strict types, if you truly need to coalesce 'similar' values, e.g. string "4" to integer 4.

Comment: `PDO_Statement::bindParam()` Also throws this when the fourth argument is not an (int)

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs when you perform calculations with variables that use letters combined with numbers (alphanumeric), for example 24kb, 886ab ...

I had the error in the following function

```
function get_config_bytes($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);       
    switch($last) {
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }
    return $this->fix_integer_overflow($val);
}
```

The application uploads images but it didn't work, it showed the following warning:

[image]

**Solution:** The `intval()` function extracts the integer value of a variable with alphanumeric data and creates a new variable with the same value but converted to an integer with the `intval()` function. Here is the code:

```
function get_config_bytes($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    $intval = intval(trim($val));
    switch($last) {
        case 'g':
            $intval *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $intval *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $intval *= 1024;
    }
    return $this->fix_integer_overflow($intval);
}
```

The function fix_integer_overflow

```
// Fix for overflowing signed 32 bit integers,
// works for sizes up to 2^32-1 bytes (4 GiB - 1):
protected function fix_integer_overflow($size) {
    if ($size < 0) {
        $size += 2.0 * (PHP_INT_MAX + 1);
    }
    return $size;
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are answering a different question -- not the one posted at the top of this page.  Please only answer the question that is asked.  This is why we require askers to provide a [mcve] -- so that the answers don't splinter into a thousand different directions.

Comment: the function depends on external code ... what does `$ this-> fix_integer_overflow` do?

Comment: Hi Lorenzo Magon, I add the function `fix_integer_overflow`, so you can see its use

Comment: Casting is a very wrong idea. It sweeps the problem under the rug. Instead of just casting, you must parse the string according to the expected format and validate results. For example, your own function doesn't parse the example provided in the question, 24kb, returning outright incorrect result of 24.

Answer (score 8):

`$_GET['start_date']` is not numeric is my bet, but an date format not supported by `strtotime`. You will need to re-format the date to a workable format for [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) or use combination of [explode](http://www.php.net/explode)/[mktime](http://www.php.net/mktime).

I could add you an example if you'd be kind enough to post the format you currently receive.

Comment: Casting won't fix the issue since PHP will automatically cast it when passed to the method.

Comment: I like that you identified that there isn't enough detail in the question to offer an exact answer.  This is because the [mcve] is incomplete; ergo this question should be closed instead of answered.  It's not hard to get users to post a complete question, but they will not be motivated to do so if volunteers will start firing answers//guesses in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same situation (in my case with a date value in a custom PHP field in a Drupal view), and what worked for me was using intval instead of strtotime to turn the value into an integer - because it basically was a timestamp, but in the form of a string rather than an integer. Obviously that won't be the case for everyone, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: We do not know if this technique will resolve the OP's problem because the OP did not state the value of the input data.

Answer (score 5):

This helped me a lot:

```
$new_date = date_format(date_create($old_date), 'Y-m-d');
```

Here, [`date_create()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) provides you a date object for a given date & [`date_format()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp) will set it in a given format.

for example,

```
<?php
    $date = date_create("13-02-2013");  // DateTime Object ( [date] => 2013-02-13 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York )
    echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");    // 2013-02-13
?>
```

Comment: It would help researcher a lot if you explained your snippet and why it was helpful to you.

Comment: How can you be certain that this technique will work for the question asked?  The OP has not declared the input data.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, but there is another subtle way this message can happen.  It's explained pretty well [here, in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php#95812).

Imagine this scenerio:

```
try {
  // code that triggers a pdo exception
} catch (Exception $e) {
  throw new MyCustomExceptionHandler($e);
}
```

And `MyCustomExceptionHandler` is defined roughly like:

```
class MyCustomExceptionHandler extends Exception {
  public function __construct($e) {
    parent::__construct($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
  }
}
```

This will actually trigger a new exception in the custom exception handler because the `Exception` class is expecting a number for the second parameter in its constructor, but `PDOException` might have dynamically changed the return type of `$e->getCode()` to a string.

A workaround for this would be to define you custom exception handler like:

```
class MyCustomExceptionHandler extends Exception {
  public function __construct($e) {
    parent::__construct($e->getMessage());
    $this->code = $e->getCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: Explaining exception handling may aid in understanding the problem, but it will not resolve the problem.  This is Not An Answer because it does not attempt to resolve the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

if $_GET['start_date'] is a string then convert it in integer or double to deal numerically.

```
$int = (int) $_GET['start_date']; //Integer
$double = (double) $_GET['start_date']; //It takes in floating value with 2 digits
```

Comment: You are guessing at the value of `$start_date`.  If it is `08/08/2020` then casting it as an integer or a float will not help at all.  Rather than answer this question, the correct action would be to leave a comment under the question to ask the OP to express the exact input data.

Comment: $end_suggest_time =  (int) $rowone['start_suggest_time']  + (24 * 3600);
when i add  (int) in the previus of $rowone  i dont recieve this error "Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in"

Answer (score -1):

in the name of the universe programmer

in my case i receive this error

> "Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in"

my code with above error:

`$end_suggest_time = $rowone['start_suggest_time'] + (24 * 3600);`

when i add  `(int)` in the previous of `$rowone['start_suggest_time']`  I don't receive this error

> "Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in"

`$end_suggest_time = (int) $rowone['start_suggest_time'] + (24 * 3600);`

Answer (score -1):

In my case when getting error:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

When my code is like this

```
if (date('y-m-d H:i:s') - $user_token['created_at'] < (60 * 60 * 24)) {
...
}
```

And my fixing code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
if (strtotime(date('y-m-d H:i:s')) - strtotime($user_token['created_at']) < (60 * 60 * 24)) {
...
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32484372)

Answer (score -1):

```
<td>{{(double)$template_list->administrative_approval - (double)$template_list->released_fund }} </td>
```

(double),(int) use its.