# How do I fix this error in PHP: "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Tags: php, strtotime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A non well formed numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136430/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered)

Why doesn't this work?

```
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+7 days','2035-01-01 00:00:00'));
```

The error I see is:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: I think you should consider the answer given here :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6136743/235659

Comment: The link to a possible duplicate isn't valid. Nothing at that link helps me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The second parameter of `strtotime` expects a timestamp, not a string. See the manual on [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

You can use `strtotime` again on your second parameter to get what you want:

```
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+7 days',strtotime('2035-01-01 00:00:00')));
```

Comment: Finally, I looked at at least 10 answers to this problem, no one else explained the need to convert it to a timestamp before using strtotime() again.