# adding one month to date using strtotime error with formatting php

Tags: php, date

Somebody please help me to format the date. I'm not familiar with date formatting. 
I want to increment the date by one month but i get this error:

> "A non well formed numeric value encountered"

```
$bseDate=$_POST['lastBseDate']; //this will return 2014-04-03
$nextBse = date('y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month", $bsedate));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A non well formed numeric value encountered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136430/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, `strtotime` gives a timestamp from a string, but since you are providing the optional base time it needs to be a timestamp as well:

```
$nextBse = date('y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($bseDate)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Datetime()` for all date manipulation as it takes Daylight Savings Time and more into consideration and is more readable and maintainable.

```
$nextBse = (new DateTime($_POST['lastBseDate']))->modify('+1 month')->format('y-m-d');
```