# CodeIgniter: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: codeigniter, date, date-format

I'm working with CI and it is successfully echoing the proper expire date, but I am also getting this error:

A non well formed numeric value encountered

```
    $expire_datetime = date('g:ia \o\n l jS F Y',strtotime($row->created, "+2weeks"));  
    echo $expire_datetime;
```

Comment: Check [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136430/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered#answers) answers.

Comment: I did, I'm not quite understanding those answers really.

Comment: Maybe you would like to use `date_format()` function. Check the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#107757).

Comment: Tried that. Still works but throws this:        date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

Comment: I think you would need to concatenate second parameter in strtotime() function as: `strtotime($row->created . " + 2 weeks")`

Comment: That was it man! You rock!

Answer (score 0):

All you coding is correct. problem is with `+2weeks`.  When you use `strtotime()` function you need to keep `<space>` on between text`(+2<SPACE>weeks)`.

Examples([from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp))

```
<?php
    echo(strtotime("now") . "<br>");
    echo(strtotime("3 October 2005") . "<br>");
    echo(strtotime("+5 hours") . "<br>");
    echo(strtotime("+1 week") . "<br>");
    echo(strtotime("+1 week 3 days 7 hours 5 seconds") . "<br>");
    echo(strtotime("next Monday") . "<br>");
    echo(strtotime("last Sunday"));
?>
```

So your Final Well form code is

```
$expire_datetime = date('g:ia \o\n l jS F Y',strtotime($row->created, "+2 weeks"));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function requires relative date format in first argument. Second argument is optional and can be unix time stamp.