# A non well formed numeric value encountered in index.php on line

Tags: php

A non well formed numeric value encountered in /storage/h1/482/498482/public_html/index.php on line 43

My code is:

```
$update_date = date("d/m/Y", mktime(0,0,0, $updateArr[1], $updateArr[0], $updateArr[2]));
```

In php 5.0 everything was fine. In php 5.3 the message above is appeared. What is the problem?

Comment: does your `$updateArr` all contains only integer values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A non well formed numeric value encountered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136430/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered)