# Having trouble with strftime and mktime in php pdo

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I have here:

```
<td><?php print strftime("%d %b. %Y %I:%M %p",mktime($row['c_date'])); ?></td>
```

and the output is

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\My-Sample\class.crud.php on line 180
19 Jan. 2018 12:05 AM
```

Comment: what is the value of `$row['c_date']` ?

Comment: I set it datetime and current time stamp

Comment: 2018-01-19 11:11:4

Comment: I don't see any issue `echo strftime("%d %b. %Y %I:%M %p",mktime(time()));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A non well formed numeric value encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136430/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered)

Comment: I alreay saw it but does not help :( @WaqasBukhary

Comment: strftime("%d %b. %Y %I:%M %p",mktime(time($row['c_date']))); works like a charm thank you very much :D @Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second argument of `strftime` is timestamp, and you are passing a string. Use `strtotime($row['c_date'])` function in the second argument and all will be good.

Following are the arguments of strftime from the php docs.

```
string strftime ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

Hence this will work

```
<td><?php if (isset($row['c_date'])) {
    print strftime("%d %b. %Y %I:%M %p",strtotime($row['c_date'])); 
} ?></td>
```

Comment: print strftime("%d %b. %Y %I:%M %p",mktime(time($row['c_date'])));

Comment: Yes time() will do since it returns timestamp

Comment: I still have wrong output 01 Jan. 1970 08:00 AM T_T 1970 and its time always show 8:00 am

Comment: What is the value in the $row['c_date']? can you echo and let me know.

Comment: 2018-01-19 11:35:16

Comment: Check the answer.