# How to solve a non well formed numeric value encountered in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I am having an error. A non well formed numeric value encountered. Kindly check my code below and guide me what I am doing wrong:

```
...
    $i++;
    $item_count += $item['quantity'];
    $sub_total += ($product['price'] * $item['quantity']);
    $sub_total = (float)$sub_total;

}
$tax_rate = 18;

$tax = ($tax_rate * $sub_total) / 100;
// Here I am having an error - A non well formed numeric value encountered
$tax = number_format($tax, 2); // 2 decimal digit
$grand_total = $tax + $sub_total;
```

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong.
Your suggestions would be welcome.
Thank You

Comment: [Duplicated See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136430/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered)

Comment: I have to use strtotime?

Comment: **Hint**- This usually means that your converting a `string` to `integer` you will still get your desired result if the string was an `integer` in `string format` but with a warning.  **Example1:** `$number='1'; `//This an integer in a string format. **Example2:** `$number=1;` //This is a pure integer.

Comment: for this here I have used (float)$sub_total;

Comment: strtotime has nothing to do with your problem see above comment

Comment: Try `echo is_int($sub_total);` and see what it gives you

Comment: ok I am checking I did not know is_int() before. Thanks. I am a beginner 20days old in programming.

Comment: Don't give up the journey is long and annoying :)

Comment: The value is 1379

Comment: `number_format($tax,2)` //this is your error number format returns a string

Comment: if you want to still use `number_format()` then use it at the end of your calculation or assign a different value that you wont use in your calculations for it.

Comment: Hey Great! Its working now! Thank You. You are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number_format is function used for formatting strings. You may and should use it to view values, not to calculate them. You may change lines:

```
$grand_total = $tax + $sub_total;
$tax = number_format($tax,2);
```

But it would be a bit safer to use another variable:

```
$view_tax = number_format($tax,2);
$grand_total = $tax + $sub_total;
// now $grand_total uses $tax and to view
// tax, just use $view_tax variable
```

Comment: Give the user a chance to delete the question if user feels like by answering what could have been solved with comments the user can no longer delete the question as users problem has been solve in comments answer was unnecessary.